# IF or Switch inside of an array

Tags: php

Is it possible to do a if/else or switch statement inside an array ?

For example i have this array

```
'images' => array(
          array(
                'link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer .'.jpg'
          ),
      ),
```

Now i want to check if there are more than 1 images, if yes add an array.
My thought was this, but it doesnt work.

```
    <?php

$images = (string)$product->aantalfotos;

'images' => array(
    switch ($images) {
        case 1:
            array(
                'link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer .'.jpg'
            ),
        break;

        case 2:
            array(
                'link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer .'.jpg'
            ),
            array(
                'link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer .'_2.jpg'
            ),
        break;

        case 3:
            array(
                'link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer .'.jpg'
            ),
            array(
                'link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer .'_2.jpg'
            ),
            array(
                'link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer .'_3.jpg'
            ),
        break;
    }
),
```

Comment: of course, but it does not work :)

Comment: Short answer: no; *of course, but it does not work* Why do you ask then?

Comment: Then you have your answer. ;-)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the if or switch statement first and then create the arrays in that?

Comment: I want to know how i can do an statement ?
Is there nothing option to do something like this ?

Otherwise i would not know how to check if there are more than 1 images ( interger ) and if so make one more array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php

$images = (string)$product->aantalfotos;

for ($working = array(), $i = 1, $suffix = ''; $i <= $images; $i++)
{
    $working[] = array('link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/'.(string)$product->artikelnummer.$suffix.'.jpg');
    $suffix = '_'.($i + 1);
}

// Use $working in 'images' => $working

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

aantalfotos;

```
        switch($images) {
            case 1:
                $x = array('link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer . '.jpg');
            break;

            case 2:
                $x = array('link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer . '.jpg',
                    array('link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer . '_2.jpg'));
            break;

            case 3:
                $x = array('link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer . '.jpg',
                array('link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer . '_2.jpg'),
                array('link' => 'http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/500/' . (string)$product->artikelnummer . '_3.jpg'));
            break;
        }

if(!empty($x)) {
    $images[] = ($x);
}

print_r($images);
```